# Wrong 3D plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to create 3D plots in Matlab, and I have practically no experience. I'd really like to draw the figure described by these equations:

```
x = cos(u) sinh(t) / (cosh(t) - cos(u));    
y = cos(u) sin(u) / (cosh(t) - cos(u));    
z = sin(u);
```

where both u and t vary from -pi to pi. This is what *Paul Bourke* calls [*Ghost Plane*](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/ghostplane/).

```
clc
clear
a = -pi:.01:pi;
b = -pi:.01:pi;
[U,T] = meshgrid(a,b);
X = (cos(U).*sinh(T))./(cosh(T)-cos(U));
Y = (cos(U).*sin(U))./(cosh(T)-cos(U));
Z = sin(U);
figure
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

With the code, I get something... indescribable. How do I plot the figure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct. You just need to zoom in.

Some tips to make this more viewable:

- Use less fine grids, by changing `a = ...` and `b = ...` to: `linspace(-pi,pi,40);`
- Add this `,'FaceColor','none','EdgeColor','interp');` to the `surf` command to only plot the lines and those in color.
- Add this `axis equal vis3d;` after the `surf` command, so the axis will have correct scaling and behave well while rotating.
- Add `whitebg('black');` and `grid off;` to make the background black.
- Change to `surf(X,Y,Z,-U,...);` and add `colormap('HSV');` if you want the same colors as in the original.
- `set(gca,'xtick',[]); set(gca,'xticklabel',[]); set(gca,'yticklabel',[]); set(gca,'ytick',[]);` to remove the axis ticks
- You might want to use the `cameratoolbar` to: Change the projection to *perspective projection*, zoom all the way out, move the camera in very close, to get nice perspective distortions.

**Voilà:**

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Just one more question: how do I change colours? My plot is more yellowish

Comment: Did you add the `colormap` I mentioned above? You can also see `doc colormap` to have a look at all the different ones. (you can even define one of your own)

Comment: Nice! Without wanting it you just summarised all the main features of visualiztion in Matlab! great answer

Comment: @AnderBiguri: We're here to enlighten, aren't we? :-)